# core input grayed out during preview in Designer

Tags: polymer, polymer-designer-tool

While using the designer i am following the Google I/O video which talks about creating a simple google map search app. In preview the core-input field does not take any input. It stays grayed out and non editable. Is this something anyone has tried and seen the same issue?

Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`core-input` does look like disabled 'cause it doesn't have any styling. According to the official [link](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-input) -

> core-input is an unstyled single-line input field.

I believe what you were looking for is `paper-input` which is styled in favor of material design. Have a look at this [demo](https://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/preview.html#6178f2b527425de75206), I created it followed by Rob's video a while ago.